# Calculate experience of employee in months

Tags: sql-server

How can I calculate experience of an employee in months ? Like if an employee's Joining Date was 2016-01-10 So till now it should be 24 months. I am trying this query but it is only giving one year's experience.

```
    Select [EI].[FirstName]+' '+[EI].[LastName] AS [EmployeeName], [EI].[DOJ],
     (CONVERT(Varchar(2),DATEDIFF(YEAR, [DOJ], GETDATE()) % 12)) AS [EXPERIENCE]
FROM EmployeeInfo EI
```

Comment: Show input data and desired output.

Comment: Try Select datediff(MONTH,'2016-01-10',GetDate())

Answer (score 2):

Use the DATEDIFF function with "month" as the datepart input argument. This DATEDIFF syntax would look like this using your example.

```
DATEDIFF(month, [DOJ], GETDATE())
```

Microsoft's [DATEDIFF function page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql) has more details about this function.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select [EI].[FirstName]+' '+[EI].[LastName] AS [EmployeeName], [EI].[DOJ],
(CONVERT(Varchar(2),DATEDIFF(YEAR, [DOJ], GETDATE()))) AS [EXPERIENCE]
FROM EmployeeInfo EI
```

This worked fine for me. I was dividing my query with 12 which is why it was not moving ahead from year. My bad I guess.

Comment: JohnH has a better solution.